# How to group a dataframe by year, apply sum and make into a new dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a data frame with two columns:

```
Date                Amount
2024-01-04          0.34
2023-09-28          0.33
2023-06-22          0.33
2023-03-23          0.32
2023-01-05          0.32
2006-04-06          0.12
2006-01-05          0.12
2005-10-06          0.10
2005-07-07          0.10
2005-04-07          0.09
```

I want to groupby this dataframe by the year (i.e., 2023, 2006, 2005) and apply sum to get total amount, paid in a given year.

I need to have a new dataframe with two columns "year" (i.e., 2023, 2006, 2005) and sum.

I am using this function:

```py
df = df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.year, as_index=False).agg({'Gross Amount':'sum'})
```

As a result, I am getting a one-dimentional dataframe with only one column (Amounts) when I print `df`.

Thank you!

Comment: try `df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.year)['Amount'].sum().reset_index()`

Comment: @QuangHoang Thank you! reset_index() does what I need. Can you make it into answer so I can accept it?